# Problema con encondig en conexión a postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, encoding

Mi base de datos tiene codificación SQL_ASCII
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la conexión configurada en mi java

```
private PostgreSQLJDBC(String serverdb, String portdb, String dbname, String user, String pass) {
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://"+serverdb+":"+portdb+"/"+dbname;
        driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
        usuario = user;
        password = pass;
     
        try{
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

La clase que consume información de la base de datos es:

```
     Connection con = PostgreSQLJDBC.getConnection(serverdb, portdb, dbname, user, pass);
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    
     ResultSet rs = null;
     rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT nombre FROM persona"); // <- Aquí manda la excepción
```

Todo funciona correctamente como se espera **EXCEPTO** cuando el nombre de la persona tiene una ***ñ*** por ejemplo.
El error es el siguiente:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe1 0x6c 0x69
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2674)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2364)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:354)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:484)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:404)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:325)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:311)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:287)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:239)
at com.vass.ConnectRealm.jmsMessagePub(ConnectRealm.java:88)
at com.vass.ConnectRealm.main(ConnectRealm.java:333)
```

He intentado usar el **?charSet=ISO-8859-1** como [aquí](http://library.gxtechnical.com/gxdlsp/pub/SAC/hsac_10507,S.html) lo indica pero no funciona.

**NO** puedo cambiar nada en el servidor ni en la base de datos, tengo que solucionarlo desde mi java.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Prueba cambiar `charSet` por `characterEncoding`.

Comment: No funcionó, alguna otra idea?

Comment: Prueba cambiar el set de caracteres por defecto de Java con estos 2 parámetros de la VM `-Dfile.encoding="ISO-8859-1" -Dsun.jnu.encoding="ISO-8859-1"` y para verificar si configuras correctamente ejecuta `System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().displayName());`